# Infinite sum not evaluated unless split into even and odd terms

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, summation

This sum

```
s = Sum[Gamma[k/2]/(2 k!), {k, 1, ∞}]
```

$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}{2 k!}$

is returned unevaluated (version 10.1.0).

However, if we split even from odd k the sums are done

```
se = Sum[Gamma[k]/(2 (2 k)!), {k, 1, ∞}]

(*
  1/4 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1}, {3/2, 2}, 1/4]
*)

so = Sum[Gamma[k - 1/2]/(2 (2 k - 1)!), {k, 1, ∞}]

(*
  1/2 π Erfi[1/2]
*)
```

And the sum $se + so$ is indeed $s$, as can be checked numerically.

```
se + so // N

(* 1.23826 *)

sn = NSum[Gamma[k/2]/(2 k!), {k, 1, ∞}]

(* 1.23826 *)
```

Question: how can I get *Mathematica* to discover this simple splitting by itself?

Comment: _Mathematica_ is not an AI program; at least, not yet. So sometimes you have to do the thinking while _Mathematica_ does the drudge work.

Comment: @m_goldberg You might know me as a strong advocat of "man-machine-interaction" in solving MMA problems, and have shown this on several occasions here, including this one.

Comment: But I still don't understand what you mean by "tell" and "discover for itself" if not AI, or what kind of an answer you expect

Comment: @m_goldberg I didn't use the word "tell" as you suggest. Let me summarize: I have shown how to derive the exact symbolic result of the sum. My question is just if there is perhaps some command like Simplify etc. which helps MMA to find the result. BTW this is the first instance in more than 11 years of using MMA that someone comes up with the term AI in such a simple context ;-)

Comment: A workaround: `Sum[Gamma[k/2]/(2 k Gamma[k]), {k, 1, ∞}]`

Answer (score 4):

Just regularize:

```
 Sum[Gamma[k/2]/(2 k!), {k, 1, ∞}, Regularization -> "Abel"]
```

> `1/4 (2 π Erfi[1/2] + HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1}, {3/2, 2}, 1/4])`

Comment: Thank you very much @yarchik that's what I was looking for. You can also use the neutral form Regularization->True

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this give you some idea:

```
    Plus[Sequence @@ Table[Gamma[k/2]/k!, {k, 1, 1000}]] // N
so = Plus[
   Sequence @@ Table[Gamma[k - 1/2]/(2 (2 k - 1)!), {k, 1, 1000}]] // N
se = Plus[Sequence @@ Table[Gamma[k]/(2 k)!, {k, 1, 1000}]] // N
se + so
```

I know this is not an answer but I am under 50 reputation and can not post comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But you will find that I did just this - and complete up to k = oo - in my question.